# How to know which UI Test is running in a Class? When the second test starts

Tags: swift, xcode7, ui-testing, xcode-ui-testing

I've a class of UI Test with many methods of test and when run the first test I need to do login on my app and the following methods I don't need because the test doesn't reinstall the app.

So, I tried to create a variable boolean on my class but at the begging of each test the var is recreated.

I know that the tests is running by alphabetical order but I think it's not a good way to do, I want to make sure that my second test is running and the third and etc...

Anyone knows how to help me?

Answer (score 1):

In your UItestFile, create a property loggedIn

```
@interface UITests()
@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL loggedIn; //use this to know wether user is logged in or not
@end

-(void)testLogin
{ if //user logged set the loggedIn flag and skip the test
  { self.loggedIn = YES;
    return;
  }
 else
  //perform login and test login flow
}
```

Tests does not necessarily run in alphabetical order, to change order of test you can use testInvocation and always call testLogin first.

```
+ (NSArray <NSInvocation *> *)testInvocations
{
    NSArray *testNames = @[@"testLogin",
                           @"testY",
                           @"testB",
                           @"testC",
                           @"testA",
                          ];

    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString *testName in testNames)
    {
        SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(testName);
        NSMethodSignature *methodSignature = [self instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector];
        NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:methodSignature];
        invocation.selector = selector;
        [result addObject:invocation];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: For Swift explorers, loggedIn property (non-optional type) need to be defined a Static property type since each XCTest instantiate new instance of test class for each test() method and instance variable will be reset to its default value.